# Limit maximum character input on Laravel form element

Tags: forms, laravel, laravel-blade

So I have this form and I want to limit the user input on the text boxes to only 12, so here is the code

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('Bname', 'Breed Name:') }}
    {{ Form::text('bname', null, 12, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <div class="form-group">
  {{ Form::label('Bname','Breed Name:')}}
  {{Form::text('bname',null,12,['class' => 'form-control', 'maxlength' => '12'])}}
  </div>
```

Comment: wow this is what i am looking for, is there a way that user can see the available characters that they can still type. Thanks alot!

Comment: you will need javascript for this. Here is an example: http://www.scriptiny.com/2012/09/jquery-input-textarea-limiter/